# Create node -MAAS(power off)

Tags: shutdown, maas

I am trying to add nodes in the MAAS. When I add the node from PXE, the computer shuts down (power off) and it appears as Accepted. But even if the wake on lan type, nothing happens after and the node continues as OFFLINE . What should I do?

Comment: What set-up are you using? Does the node power on when the WOL signal is sent?

Comment: No. the machine is not called after the won has been sent. I'm using 12.04

Comment: Are you trying to do this with virtual machines? Does the node have WOL capability?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure wakeonlan is installed, it is not installed by default

```
sudo apt-get install wakeonlan
```